# How to retrieve full definition of external func/proc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting, sqlclr

I'd like to write a procedure to build the sql code to define all func/procs in given assembly. 
It is simple for procedures and scalar functions -
 iterating  sys.assemblies/modules/objects/parameters I can prepare code for create func/proc.

But I cannot find where the definition of the table returned by the tv function is stored. Scripting of the functions like that is possible, so - the definition of the table have to be written somwhere..

By the way - second question: is there some tool to create sql definition of func/proc basing on C# code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Tables, Table-Valued Functions (Inline, SQL MultiStatement, and SQLCLR), and Views are maintained in the `sys.columns` system catalog view (and `sys.all_columns`).

```
SELECT obj.[name], obj.[type_desc], col.[name]
FROM   sys.objects obj
INNER JOIN sys.columns col
        ON col.[object_id] = obj.[object_id]
ORDER BY obj.[type_desc], obj.[name], col.[name];
```

You will need to join to `sys.types` to get the full datatype name.

However, there is very little point to scripting things out as you are doing since:

1. If the T-SQL wrapper objects (for the SQLCLR methods within the Assembly) were created by a script you wrote, then you already have those `CREATE` statements, and
2. If the T-SQL wrapper objects were created by SSDT (with or without Visual Studio), then you already have the "create" script (if you opted to have it get generated upon each build) and the incremental "publish" script.

In either case, those objects were created from a T-SQL script that you should already have. Unless, I suppose, you were handed a Database that had the objects and the deployment scripts aren't available for some reason.

> Is there some tool to create T-SQL definition of func/proc based on C# code ?

From the database or the DLL / Assembly? There are some tools that can be used to script any type of object out of the database. You can also use the .NET SMO classes to script out the definitions from the database. If you want to scan the DLL / Assembly, you would need to use the .NET Reflection classes to iterate over each method and look at the `SqlFunction`, `SqlProcedure`, `SqlFacet` attributes / decorators.

Comment: > deployment scripts aren't available for some reason.

Comment: Simple - thx :-)  Second question refers to source code ( C#) or DLL.